# Returning a value from C# function called using window.external.notify

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am making an app for windows phone 8 using phonegap.I called C# function from my javacript using `window.external.Notify([commandname])`.It calls the C# code correctly. But I want to return a string value from my C# code back to that javascript function.
For solution-
I tried using `InvokeScript()` method to call a javascript function and passed my result as a parameter to it. But it is giving me `OutOfMemoryException`.

My C# code is-

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CordovaView.Loaded += CordovaView_Loaded;
            CordovaView.Browser.ScriptNotify+=Browser_ScriptNotify;


        }

        private void Browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            string commandStr = e.Value.ToString();
            IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            //get the key data
            if (commandStr == kToken + "-get" || commandStr == kMSISDN + "-get" || commandStr == kTermsAccepted + "-get" || commandStr == kUserDetails + "-get")
            {
                string[] keys = commandStr.Split('-');
                key = keys[0];
                if (!settings.Contains(key))
                {
                    sampledata = null;

                }
                else
                {
                    sampledata = (string)settings[key];

                }
                this.CordovaView.Browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
                this.CordovaView.Browser.InvokeScript("mydata", data);
            }
            else(commandStr == "removedata")
            {
                settings.Clear();
            }
        }

        private void CordovaView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            this.CordovaView.Loaded -= CordovaView_Loaded;

        }
    }


}
```

Below is my javascript code-

```
function getDataForKey(key) {
         window.external.Notify(key + '-get');
         senddata: return data;
}

function mydata(inputdata)
{
    alert(inputdata);
    data = inputdata;
    alert('Invoked script is running');
    goto: senddata;
}
```

Please help me out on this. I am new to phonegap. So I am not able to understand how to call from javascript to C# and vice versa. I looked for a solution in phonegap documentation too,but to no relief.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PhoneGap/Cordova and do what you try to do in a platform independent way, cordova plugin mechanism is there to help. You should be implementing your own cordova plugin:

See [Plugin Development Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)

And windows native side implementation details are [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_wp8_plugin.md.html#Windows%20Phone%20Plugins).

Comment: I have even called up using plugins. But it seems as if my app is not recognizing these plugins.

Comment: Then you should check plugin installation using cli, it's a headache, especially if you implement your own and don't want to put it in github. Try starting with a simple plugin already available in github, then proceed with your own plugin, like echo sample in cordova. Believe me you will need plugins!

Comment: Ok. Thankyou for your reply. I will try implementing it.

Comment: I tried installing plugin from github too. But it is giving me error "git" command line tool is not installed.

Comment: So? error is pretty informative, why don't you install git command line tool to your system??

Comment: I even tried to add git command line tool. I get erraneous bug list which prompts "not able to add it"

Comment: I want to ask if it is possible implementing Notify and InvokeScript methods to perform the same?